# Mockito thenReturn not working as expected

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I'm having problem with mockito. I'm mocking a class and then using `thenReturn()` on on of its method. but seems like something is going wrong. here is the code.

TestCode:

```
 public void getCardsTest() {
    FeatureFragmentPresenterImpl presenter = new FeatureFragmentPresenterImpl();
    GroupFeatureData data = Mockito.mock(GroupFeatureData.class);

    FeatureFragmentView view = Mockito.mock(FeatureFragmentView.class);

    presenter.init(view, data);
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> errorObservable = Observable.error(new IOException());
    assertNotNull(observable);
    Mockito.when(data.getCards(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
            Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).
            thenReturn(errorObservable);

    presenter.getAllCards(new Contact(new Name("ssd")), -1);     
}
```

Presenter code :

```
public void getAllCards(IContact iContact, int lastIndex) {

    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> allCardsResponseObservable = mGroupFeatureData.getCards(path, id, 10, lastIndex);
    allCardsResponseObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) -------> Test Failing because NPE here
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

            });
}

  public void init(FeatureFragmentView featureFragmentView,
                  GroupFeatureData groupFeatureData) {
    this.mGroupFeatureData = groupFeatureData;
    this.mFeatureFragmentView = featureFragmentView;
}
```

Even though i'm mocking response of `data.getCards()` in Test, In presenter it is throwing NPE whereas it should just operate on mocked Observable that is `errorObservable`. what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE tells us that this line:

```
mGroupFeatureData.getCards(path, id, 10, lastIndex);
```

... returns `null` which implies that the actual method call and the method call which you mocked here ...

```
Mockito.when(data.getCards(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).
        thenReturn(errorObservable);
```

... do not match. The code supplied shows this *actual* call:

```
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> allCardsResponseObservable = 
    mGroupFeatureData.getCards(path, id, 10, lastIndex);
```

Breaking this call down we can say that:

- The third argument `10` is an int so this will match the given argument matcher: `Mockito.anyInt()`
- The fourth argument `lastIndex` is declared as an int so this will match the given argument matcher: `Mockito.anyInt()`
- The **type** of the first and second argments is not clear from your code extract since we do not see where `path` and `id` are declared but unless they are **both** of type `String` then the given argument matchers for these parameters (`Mockito.anyString()`) will not match and hence the mocked call will return `null`.

So, it looks to me like one or other of `path` and `id` are not actually of type `String`. It would be useful if you could update your question to show where these types are declared.

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious things just need a second pair of eyes. Happens to everyone :)